# How to troubleshoot ECONNREFUSED error?

Tags: node.js, d3.js, redis, derbyjs

I'm trying to get the `d3.js` demo given [here](https://github.com/enjalot/derby-barchart) to work.

I'm following along the instructions in the `README.md` file.  I get the `npm install` step to work, but the next step, `node server`, fails:

```
% node server
Master pid  16196
16197 listening. Go to: http://localhost:3030/

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED
    at RedisClient.on_error (/Users/yrstruly/tmp/derby-barchart/node_modules/redis/index.js:189:24)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/yrstruly/tmp/derby-barchart/node_modules/redis/index.js:95:14)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at net.js:440:14
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

It looks like the code is expecting to have some process listening to port 6379, but the `README` says nothing about this.

I'm quite unfamiliar with most of the software used by this demo.  In particular, I know very little about `node.js`, `derby`, and `redis`.  Therefore, I'm following the steps in the `README` rather blindly.  Any help with troubleshooting this error would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you install and launch Redis on the same computer than node.JS?

Comment: Nope.  (I've been following the steps in the README somewhat religiously.)  Thanks for the suggestion.  I'll give it a try.